# InterBase select for 2 related tables

Tags: select, interbase

I have the following tables

```
ControlTypeColorsStyle as T1
  ControlType     Char 10
  ColorsStyleName Char 10
  FillColorName   Char 20
  StrokeColorName Char 20

ColorNameColorHex as T2
  ColorName       Char 20
  ColorHex        Char 10
```

My goal is to get the following table

```
ColorHexForColorTypeAndColorsStyle as T3
  ControlType     Char 10
  ColorsStyleName Char 10
  FillColorName   Char 20
  FillColorHex    Char 10
  StrokeColorName Char 20
  StrokeColorHex  Char 10
```

Where T1.FillColorName, T1.StrokeColorname are foreign keys to T2.ColorName.

I've tried the following statement

```
select    "ControlType", "ColorStyleName",
                         "ColorName"     ,
                         "ColorHex"
from      "ControlTypeColorsStyle" T1,
          "ColorNameColorHex"      T2
where  T1."ControlType"     =  :pvControlType      and
       T1."ColorStyleName"  =  :pvControlStyleName and
       T1."FillColorName"   = T2."ColorName"       and
       T1."StrokeColorName" = T2."ColorName"
```

which returns null values.

I appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: You need to join to the second table twice to lookup up the ColorHex for each of  FillColorName and StrokeColorName.

Comment: @Brian. You mean that I have to join once for "FillColorName" and another time for "StrokeColorName". Can you please post an example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your T1 table to 2 copies of the ColorNameColorHex table.  Your original SQL would only work when FillColorName and StrokeColorName were the same value.  If they are different values and trying to just a single link to the lookup table they will always have one of the two resolve to false hence no records coming back.

For example, if FillColorName is 'red' and StrokeColorName 'black' you do not have a single record in the ColorNameColorHex table that is both 'red' and 'black' at the same time.

You need the second reference to your lookup table so you can translate the FillColorName to its hex value and the second instance of the lookup is used to resolve StrokeColorName to its hex value.

Try

```
select    "ControlType", "ColorStyleName",
          "ColorName"     ,
          T2."ColorHex" "FillColorHex",
          T3."ColorHex" "StrokeColorHex"
from      "ControlTypeColorsStyle" T1,
          "ColorNameColorHex"      T2,
          "ColorNameColorHex"      T3
where  T1."ControlType"     =  :pvControlType      and
       T1."ColorStyleName"  =  :pvControlStyleName and
       T1."FillColorName"   = T2."ColorName"       and
       T1."StrokeColorName" = T3."ColorName"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you setup your table with the correct Primary Key and Foreign Key definitions, you can add matching WHERE conditions to lookup the hex value for the color name from the primary table.

```sql
create table ColorNameColorHex (
  ColorName       char(20) not null PRIMARY KEY,
  ColorHex        char(10) not null
);
create table ControlTypeColorsStyle (
  ControlType     char(10),
  ColorsStyleName char(10),
  FillColorName   char(20) REFERENCES ColorNameColorHex(ColorName),
  StrokeColorName char(20) REFERENCES ColorNameColorHex(ColorName)
);
```

and your sample data is...

```
select * from ColorNameColorHex;

COLORNAME            COLORHEX   
==================== ========== 

LIME                 #00FF00    
CYAN                 #00FFFF    
ORANGERED            #FF4500    
CHOCOLATE            #D2691E    

select * from ControlTypeColorsStyle;

CONTROLTYPE COLORSSTYLENAME FILLCOLORNAME        STROKECOLORNAME      
=========== =============== ==================== ==================== 

FG          BOLD            LIME                 ORANGERED            
BG          SHADE           CYAN                 ORANGERED            
FG          BOLD            LIME                 CHOCOLATE            
BG          SHADE           CHOCOLATE            ORANGERED
```

you can write your query as below. For each value in the FillColorName and StrokeColorName columns from ControlTypeColorsStyle table, the WHERE condition matches it up the proper record from ColorNameColorHex.

```sql
/* implicit join of the tables */
select    ControlType, ColorsStyleName,
          T1.FillColorName,
          T2.ColorHex FillColorHex,
          T1.StrokeColorName,
          T3.ColorHex StrokeColorHex
from      ControlTypeColorsStyle T1,
          ColorNameColorHex      T2,
          ColorNameColorHex      T3
where  T1.FillColorName   = T2.ColorName       and
       T1.StrokeColorName = T3.ColorName;
```

Alternatively, you can use column level sub-queries as follows...

```sql
/* column sub-queries */
select    ControlType, ColorsStyleName,
          FillColorName,
          (select ColorHex from ColorNameColorHex where ColorName=T1.FillColorName) FillColorHex,
          StrokeColorName,
          (select ColorHex from ColorNameColorHex where ColorName=T1.StrokeColorName) StrokeColorHex
from      ControlTypeColorsStyle T1;
```

Output data is...

```
CONTROLTYPE COLORSSTYLENAME FILLCOLORNAME        FILLCOLORHEX STROKECOLORNAME      STROKECOLORHEX 
=========== =============== ==================== ============ ==================== ============== 

FG          BOLD            LIME                 #00FF00      ORANGERED            #FF4500        
BG          SHADE           CYAN                 #00FFFF      ORANGERED            #FF4500        
FG          BOLD            LIME                 #00FF00      CHOCOLATE            #D2691E        
BG          SHADE           CHOCOLATE            #D2691E      ORANGERED            #FF4500
```